What is the official position of major Sankara mathams on Adi Sankaracharya's birth details?
Scholars assign a birth- date of 788 AD, although even that has been disputed.
I'd like to know the official position of the  Amnaya Peethmas
Govardhana Math in the East.
Sringeri Sharada Peetham in the South.
Dwaraka Math in the West.
Jyotir Math in the North.
and Kanchi
regarding the
(1) date and place of birth
(2) parentage, including caste background
of Adi Sankaracharya.

Caste is Nambodiri brahmin of Kaladi.. father Sivaguru, mother Aryamba.. DOB as per Kanchi Peetham 2593 (509 BCE)
